# Серверная генерация графиков - стоит ли?

Tags: html, seo

На сайте на некоторых страницах есть несколько графиков. Графики сначала генерируются на сервере (что-то вроде превью), затем на клиенте график снова рендерится, заменяет превью и становится интерактивным.

Пример страницы: [(графики внизу)](https://performstars.com/players/thorsten-hohmann)

Вопрос: может стоит пропустить этап генерации превью?

Руководство объясняет что превью графиков нужны для seo. Я не нашел инфы что изображения как-то используются в поисковой оптимизации (кроме атрибута `alt`). А визуально превью вообще не видно, так как графики находятся не в начале страницы. Только загрузку страницы замедляют, одни минусы.

Может кто-то знает в чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Можно предположить, что эти графики будут показываться в поиске по картинкам. Правда, без нормально прописанного атрибута `alt` они будут показываться очень плохо, но всё-таки https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpQZ4.png

Comment: Кстати, все равно в поиск попал вариант с клиента, не серверное превью)

Comment: Не понял о чём вы, эта картинка совершенно очевидно лежит на сервере https://performstars.com/assets/img/graphs/gaF2iR9YqsNZovQtW_distance.png

Comment: Действительно, спасибо